# Android Send multiple event properties Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm looking for a way to sent multiple event properties to GA, on the documentation page i found this code:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
    .setAction(getString(actionId))
    .setLabel(getString(labelId))
    .build());
```

But i didn't find a way to add values to the event.
Basically what i want is send an event like this:

```
Category : SomeCat
Action : SomeAction
Label1 : label1
Value1 : value1
Label2 : label2
Value2 : value2
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use Google Analytics Custom Dimensions and Metrics.

Google explain dimensions as being the 'rows' in a report and metric's as being the 'columns'. Custom ones effectively allow you include your own custom data in events to send from the app to the Google Analytics server.

There is information and examples on using them with the latest SDK here:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets

One important thing to note is that you need to set up the Dimension and Metrics indices in your google analytics account first.

Answer (score 0):

Each event hit only supports one category, one action, and one label. You can either sent multiple events or as Mick suggested use custom metrics and dimensions. Sending multiple events is not recommended as there is a daily limit (like 500) on the number of hits you can send and also maximum rate you can send hit (after 30 hits you get limited to not more then 2 hits per second).